# CDF of $\frac{X_1}{X_2X_3a}$, where $X_1$, $X_2$, and $X_3$ have exp. distributions

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable

Problem:

Let $X_0$, $X_1$, $X_2$, and $X_3$ be four independent exponential random variables with the PDFs $f_{X_i}(x_i)={1\over \lambda_i} \exp(-\frac{x_i}{\lambda_i})$ where ($i=0,1,2,3$).

Let $X=\frac{X_0}{b}$ and $Y=\frac{X_1}{X_2X_3a}$ (where $a$, $b$ and $x$ are positive constants) and I want to find the:

$$\eqalign{\Pr\left(\min(X,Y)\le x\right) = \Pr(X\le x) + \Pr (Y\le x) - \Pr\left(\max(X,Y)\le x\right).\tag{1}}$$

The above result can be expressed in terms of the marginal distributions (only) when $X$ and $Y$ are independent, for then (1) becomes:
$$\eqalign{\Pr\left(\min(X,Y)\le x\right) &= F_X(x) + F_Y(x) - F_X(x)F_Y(x) \\&= 1 - (1-F_X(x))(1-F_Y(x)).\tag{2}}$$

My attempted Soloution:

$$\eqalign F_X(x)=X\leq x=1-exp(-xb)$$

and

$$\eqalign {F_Y(x) &=Y\leq x \\&=\frac{X_1}{X_2X_3a}\leq x}$$ after conditioning on $X_1$ and then on $X_3$
$$\eqalign {&=\int_0^\infty \frac{z_1}{X_2X_3a} \leq x \quad f_{X_1}(Z_1) \quad dz_1
\\&=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty X_2 \geq \frac{z_1}{z_3a} \quad f_{X_1}(Z_1) \quad f_{X_3}(Z_3) \quad dz_1 dz_3 \\
&= \int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty exp(-\frac{z_1}{z_3a\lambda_2x}) \quad f_{X_1}(Z_1) \quad f_{X_3}(Z_3) \quad dz_1 dz_3\\
&=\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty exp(-\frac{z_1}{z_3a\lambda_2x}) {1\over \lambda_1} \exp( -\frac{z_1}{\lambda_1}) {1\over \lambda_3} \exp(-\frac{z_3}{\lambda_3}) dz_1 dz_3 \\}$$

Since ${1\over \lambda_1}\int_0^\infty exp(-\frac{z_1}{z_3a\lambda_2x}) \exp( -\frac{z_1}{\lambda_1}) dz_1 = \frac{z_3}{z_3+(a\lambda_1 x)}$,

let ${1\over \lambda_3}=k$ and $a\lambda_1 x=c$ then,
$$\eqalign {&={k}\int_0^\infty exp(-{z_3k}) \frac{z_3}{z_3+(c)} dz_3 \\
&=-kc \exp(ck)E_1(ck)+1}$$
where $E_1(ck)$ is the exponential integral function.

Therefore, the $min(X,Y)\leq x = 1 -\Big(exp(-xb) (kc \exp(ck)E_1(ck)\Big)$.

Any comments or pointing out mistakes will be very much appropriated.

Comment: I am afraid you have some notational difficulties.  For example, what does your equation 2 mean?  What are you trying to find, the distribution of $\min (X,Y)$?  What is $x$, and how can it equal $1 - (1-F_X(x))(1-F_Y(x))$?   (It can, but possibly only at $x=0$.)  I think a significant rewrite will be needed to make sense of what you're asking.

Comment: You might find the work easier if you were to express the event $Y\gt x$ as $X_1\gt X_2X_3ax$: there would be no quotients to work with.  Evidently the exponential integral would not arise in computing the chance of the latter event, suggesting something went wrong in your calculations.

Comment: @jbowan, Thank you for your kind reply. I have updated the question description. Can you kindly check it out again?

Comment: @whuber, Thank You sir. I have now updated the question. Can you please look at it again?